# Help formatting longtable for landscape oriented table

Tags: longtable, landscape

I am having trouble setting up the code using longtable for a table that will span multiple pages and be presented in landscape format.

It will not show the "continued on next page" tag or "Continued from Table #" at the top of the new page.

I have tried to copy the code presented in this link (http://texblog.org/2011/05/15/multi-page-tables-using-longtable/) but applied to my own application but the output is not working, maybe due to it being in landscape? Also my margins need to be specific (ie. thesis document) and the output looks like it's pushing those boundaries even though I do have them formatted. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I would have included some sample code, but it is a big table (14 columns and 53 entries, with several multi-rows thrown in) But if anyone needs the code to look at, I would be more than willing to send it along. :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We all will need your code in order to help. And we need more information on what is "not working". The code in you link will work for sure. Please reduce your table until you can show us one problem (e.g. margins issues) and then we fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{...}
\caption{my longtable caption}\\
...
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
...
\end{document}
```

The environment `landscape` will start a new page!

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I had tried to do something like:

\begin{table}
   \begin{longtable}

And it was confusing my TeX editor. I would "Vote Up" but I do not have the reputation to do that yet. Thanks again!

Comment: No! do _not_ use the `table` environment`. You can place a caption inside longtable. See edited answer. You can always vote up and accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! This solved my issue and once again my table looks pretty again!